# Determing the physical layout of HTML text and images

Tags: html, winforms, dom, layout, browser

We're trying to determine the physical layout of text and images in a div.

The div has a certain width and so lays out the text according to its word breaking rules.
How can we get the result of the layout, i.e. which text and images are on which physical lines?

Is there a DOM standard for doing this, or is this browser specific?

The results are needed by a (winforms) application hosting the browser (WebBrowser or any other hostable browser.)

Answer (score 1):

This is rendering engine specific, which yes varies from browser to browser. I don't believe there's a practical way you can replicate this without having a copy of the rendering engine internally, and trying to roll your own based on standards is a bit of fools' errand since as of yet plenty of browser vendors haven't managed to do this and they have 15 years head start on you :P

Not what you want to hear but I would reconsider your objectives.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, all you need is the [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method. I assume other libraries have similar functions.

If you're not using a good JavaScript library, you can try to gin up a one-off solution. The [jQuery source for offset()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/offset.js#L123) looks a bit complicated, though.